# How can I set the direction of a string in a DataGridViewCell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

How do I set the `RightToLeft` property for a particular DataGridViewCell in a DataGridViewColumn?

Comment: I need to set Direction not Alignment for cell

Comment: What does that mean? I'm not sure that I understand the distinction. As my answer explains, you cannot set the RightToLeft property for individual cells; it only applies to the entire control. It's designed for locales using right-to-left fonts, in which case everything on the screen would need to be right-to-left, not just one particular cell. How is "direction" different than "alignment"?

Comment: (I know this is old) The use of right-to-left fonts doesn't necessary mean that everything on the screen would needs to be right-to-left. For example you could have a DataGridView that is displaying translations of words in different langs. The column showing a RTL lang should be displayed RTL. It seems that when using a .net DataGridView to achieve this one has to set the cell font to a RTL and set CellStyle.Alignment to DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight. (although this doesn't seem to work using mono winforms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RightToLeft DatagridviewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959661/righttoleft-datagridviewcell)

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but as others said, `DataGridViewCell` and `DataGridViewColumn` don't have the `RightToLeft` property. However, there are workarounds to this problem:

1. Handle the [`CellPainting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) event and use the [`TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags.aspx) flag:

   ```
   private void RTLColumnsDGV_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.ColumnIndex == RTLColumnID && e.RowIndex >= 0)
         {
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
             TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.FormattedValue.ToString(),
             e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, e.CellStyle.ForeColor,
              TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft | TextFormatFlags.Right);
             e.Handled = true;
          }
      }
   ```

   (Code taken from [CodeProject question](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/133676/Change-the-RightToLeft-property-of-DataGridView-fo).)
2. If it's only one particular cell in the DGV, you may try to insert the invisible [RTL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) (U+200F) in the beginning of the cell content.

Comment: Point number 2 in this answer is the best option if one doesn't want to do custom painting. Unlike what some other answers say, setting the `Alignment` of the cell is NOT the same as setting its direction to RTL.

Answer (score 2):

Such a property does not exist. You need to set the [`RightToLeft` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) of the *entire control*.

I suspect that you're attempting to mis-use the property to right-justify your text. It's intended to enable support for locales that use right-to-left fonts, not for custom formatting.

If altering formatting is your goal, each `DataGridViewCell` has a [`Style` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style.aspx) that accepts an instance of the [`DataGridViewCellStyle` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.aspx). You can set its [`Alignment` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.alignment.aspx) to "MiddleRight" to align the content of the cell vertically at the middle and horizontally at the right. For more information, see: [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To do so for the whole column, use

```
dataGridView.Columns["column name"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Although I believe the individual cell's style will override this.

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as that:**

```
DataGridView1.Columns["name of column"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old post, but many times I have found answers to an old post just as helpful to point me to a solution, so I will post my solution anyway.

I did this by handling the EditingControlShowing event of the datagridview. One thing that was throwing me off when solving this was that I was trying to look for a property RightToLeft in a datagridviewcell, however that is a property of Textbox instead.

```
private void MyDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox currentCell = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (currentCell != null
            && myDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == NameOfYourColumn.Index) //or compare using column name
        {
            currentCell.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        }
    }
```