# RightToLeft DatagridviewCell

Tags: c#, right-to-left, datagridviewtextboxcell

How can i sert the property RightToLeft to a DatagridviewCell? I tried to set

Alignement property to "MiddleRight" but since my DatagridviewCell value is

Arabic and English it is not displayed as i want from right to left.

Comment: Do you mean in Win Form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution with Cell_Painting event and it works. This is the code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.FormattedValue.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, e.CellStyle.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft | TextFormatFlags.Right);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To work correctly with RightToLeft languages you should set CSS style rtl. For example:

```
private void CustomizeCellsInThirdColumn()
{
    int thirdColumn = 2;
    DataGridViewColumn column =
        dataGridView.Columns[thirdColumn];
    DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

    cell.Style.Direction = "rtl";
    column.CellTemplate = cell;
}
```

For more information read [CSS direction Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp) and [DataGridViewCell.Style Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style(v=vs.110).aspx)

direction: rtl;